# SQL - using "CASE" after an "AND"

Tags: sql

I have the following SQL query:

```
SELECT 
    ts.id, t.id, t.name
FROM 
    table1 ts
INNER JOIN 
    tabble2 t ON ts.ta = t.ta
              AND CASE 
                     WHEN :var1 = 0 THEN ts.id = :var1
                     ELSE ts.id = :var1 AND ts.em = :var2
                  END
ORDER BY  
    ts.id DESC;
```

`var1` and `var2` are variables I'm passing from code.

Is there something wrong with that query? For some reason it doesn't seem to provide the correct results.

Comment: It's generally better to use AND/OR constructions instead of case expressions in the WHERE clause.

Comment: How can i achieve the same result without the `CASE`?

Comment: See my below answer!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT ts.id, t.id, t.name
FROM table1 ts
INNER JOIN tabble2 t 
   ON ts.ta = t.ta
   AND ((:var1 = 0 AND ts.id = :var1) OR (:var1 <> 0 AND ts.id = :var1 AND ts.em = :var2))
ORDER BY ts.id desc;
```

Comment: This seems better and I think performs better - I want to say using CASE statements in a WHERE statement slows down performance.

Comment: @JamesHolland, yes, a case expression seems to be harder to optimize to get index usage.

Comment: Well this is a cumbersome way of writing this condition but it should produce the correct results...

Comment: @ZoharPeled, I know... I did just "translate" the case expression.

Answer (score 1):

I would probably write it like this:

```
SELECT ts.id, t.id, t.name
       FROM table1 ts
            INNER JOIN tabble2 t 
                   ON ts.ta = t.ta
                    AND ts.id = :var1
                    AND (:var1 = 0 OR ts.em = :var2)
                     ORDER BY ts.id desc;
```